# can't save .mp4 to storage in android

Tags: android

I am new to android, I am trying to save my video which is located in (raws) .I want to save it into external storage.

here is my code..

```
String VIDEOpath = "android.resource://com.quad14.republicdayimggif/"+R.raw.video1;

private File getDisc(){

File file = Environment.  (Environment. DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
        return new File(file,"VideoDemo");

    }



public void startSave(){

        File newfile;
    try {

        File currentFile = new File(VIDEOpath);

        File file=getDisc();
        if(!file.exists() && !file.mkdirs()){
            Snackbar.make(relativefLayoutvideo,"Soory can't create directory",Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }
        SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyymmsshhmmss");
        String date=simpleDateFormat.format(new Date());
        String name="video"+date+".mp4";
        String file_name=file.getAbsolutePath()+"/"+name;


        newfile = new File(file_name);

        if(currentFile.exists()){

            InputStream in = new FileInputStream(currentFile);
            OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(newfile);

            // Copy the bits from instream to outstream
            byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
            int len;

            while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) {
                out.write(buf, 0, len);
            }

            in.close();
            out.close();

            Snackbar.make(relativefLayoutvideo,"Video Save",Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


        }else{
            Log.v("", "Video saving failed. Source file missing.");
        }



    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: stack trace please

Comment: there no crash . if(currentFile.exists()) is not executing .

Comment: `new File(file_name)` does not create a `FIle` So `currentFile.exists()` will always be `false`.